# Problema de ventana modal que sale de la pantalla

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

Como solucionar: cuando se abre la ventana modal pero al ampliar o reducir **(crtl + -)** se me sale el contenido hacia height. Quiero hacerlo en el contenido que sea fija en el mismo lugar y sin mover de la pantalla. La tengo incluido el boostrap en el archivo principal. Sólo me interesa es centrar y ajustar a la pantalla sin salir de esta.

¿puede ser en el contenido se enfoca bien o otro tipo de contenido de "wrapper"?

**Códigos:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>estructura administrativa IGM</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estructura_administrativa/css/estilos.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estructura_administrativa/css/component.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

    <style type="text/css">

        body {
            background-color:#0e83cd;
            text-align:center;
            margin-top:650px;
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }


        .hrmedio {
              background-color: white;
              height: 3px;
              width:977px;
              margin-top:-150px;
              margin-left:240px;
              position: absolute
            }

        .hrvertical1 {
              background-color: white;
              height:373px;
              width:3px;
              margin-top:-520px;
              margin-left:710px;
              position: absolute
        }

        .hrvertical2 {
              background-color: white;
              height:90px;
              width:3px;
              margin-top:-150px;
              margin-left:240px;
              position: absolute
            }

        .hrvertical3 {
              background-color: white;
              height:90px;
              width:3px;
              margin-top:-150px;
              margin-left:555px;
              position: absolute
        }
        .hrvertical4 {
              background-color: white;
              height:90px;
              width:3px;
              margin-top:-150px;
              margin-left:885px;
              position: absolute
        }
        .hrvertical5 {
              background-color: white;
              height:90px;
              width:3px;
              margin-top:-150px;
              margin-left:1215px;
              position: absolute
        }

        .titulo {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            font-size:20px;
            }

        .texto {
            font-size: 17px;
            text-align: justify;
            text-shadow: 1px 2px 5px #575757;
        }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.tooltips').tooltip({
            trigger: 'focus'
        })
    });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

  <div>
    <div class="hrmedio"></div>
    <div class="hrvertical1"></div>
    <div class="hrvertical2"></div>
    <div class="hrvertical3"></div>
    <div class="hrvertical4"></div>
    <div class="hrvertical5"></div> 
  </div>


<div class="direccion">
    <a class="btn btn-1 btn-1a css-tooltip-left color-naranja"><div class="titulo">DIRECCIÓN</div>
        <span>
            <p>DIRECCIÓN (DIR)</p>
            <div class="texto">La Direcci&oacute;n act&uacute;a en nombre y en representaci&oacute;n del Comandante del Comando De Industria Militar e Ingenier&iacute;a. (CIMI) 
            <br><br>Tiene la facultad para celebrar los actos y contratos que se requieren para el desarrollo de los propios fines del IGM. Se rige bajo el decreto
            con fuerza de ley 2.090 y las leyes 15.284 y 16.771.<br>
            </div>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="subdirecciongeneral">
    <a class="btn btn-1 btn-1a css-tooltip-right color-naranja"><div class="titulo">SUBDIRECCIÓN</br>GENERAL</div>
        <span>
            <p>SUBDIRECCIÓN GENERAL (SDG)</p>
            <div class="texto">La Subdirecci&oacute;n General, dirige, planifica, controla y eval&uacute;a las actividades de todas las Subdirecciones, Unidad de Cuartel y Funciones primarias, con la finalidad de lograr cumplir los objetivos del IGM.</div>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="subdirecciongeografica">
    <a class="btn btn-1 btn-1a css-tooltip-top color-naranja"><div class="titulo">SUBDIRECCIÓN</br>GEOGRÁFICA</div>
        <span>
            <p>SUBDIRECCIÓN GEOGRÁFICA (SDGEO)</p>
            <div class="texto">La Subdirecci&oacute;n General, dirige, planifica, controla y eval&uacute;a las actividades de todas las Subdirecciones, Unidad de Cuartel y Funciones primarias, con la finalidad de lograr cumplir los objetivos del IGM.</div>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="subdireccioningenieria">
    <a class="btn btn-1 btn-1a css-tooltip-top color-naranja"><div class="titulo">SUBDIRECCIÓN</br>INGENIERÍA</div>
        <span>
            <p>SUBDIRECCIÓN INGENIERÍA (SDI)</p>
            <div class="texto">La Subdirecci&oacute;n de Ingenier&iacute;a, proporciona la producci&oacute;n de los productos y servicios derivados de los procesos cartogr&aacute;fico, geod&eacute;sico e investigaciones para mejorar los procesos productivos.<br><br> Su org&aacute;nica est&aacute; compuesta por el Departamento de Investigaci&oacute;n y Desarrollo, el Departamento Cartografico, el Departamento Geom&aacute;tico, el Departamento Geod&eacute;sico y el Departamento de Inform&aacute;tica.</div>
        </span>
      </a>
</div>

<div class="subdirecciongrafica">
    <a class="btn btn-1 btn-1a css-tooltip-top color-naranja"><div class="titulo">SUB.PRODUCCIÓN</br>GRÁFICA</div>
        <span>
            <p>SUBDIRECCIÓN GRÁFICA (SDPG)</p>
            <div class="texto">La Subdirecci&oacute;n de Producci&oacute;n Gr&aacute;fica, proporciona el servicio de impresi&oacute;n para productos derivados de los procesos productivos cartogr&aacute;fico y geocartogr&aacute;fico que generan la Subdirecci&oacute;n de Ingenier&iacute;a y la Subdirecci&oacute;n Geogr&aacute;fica.<br><br>Su org&aacute;nica est&aacute; compuesta por la Secci&oacute;n Pre prensa, la Secci&oacute;n Impresi&oacute;n offset, la Secci&oacute;n Impresi&oacute;n digital, la Secci&oacute;n Tipograf&iacute;a, la Secci&oacute;n Encuadernaci&oacute;n y la Secci&oacute;n Correcci&oacute;n de prueba.</div>
        </span>
    </a>
<div>

<div class="subdireccioncomercial">
    <a class="btn btn-1 btn-1a css-tooltip-left color-naranja"><div class="titulo">SUBDIRECCIÓN</br>COMERCIAL</div>
        <span>
            <p>SUBDIRECCIÓN COMERCIAL (SDC)</p>
            <div class="texto">La Subdirecci&oacute;n Comercial, realiza la comercializaci&oacute;n y difusi&oacute;n de los productos y servicios derivados de los procesos cartogr&aacute;fico y geocartogr&aacute;fico, que el IGM ofrece a la comunidad. Su org&aacute;nica est&aacute; compuesta por el Departamento de Ventas y el Departamento de Marketing.</div>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

1 ejemplo de imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Jamás obtendrás el mismo diseño sin zoom que con zoom si usas píxeles. Lo mejor en este caso es usar medidas relativas como `rem`, de ésta manera al agrandar o reducir la fuente (ctrl +/-) las unidades lo harán con ellas. Por defecto, la fuente en la mayoría de navegadores es `16px` y este a su vez equivale a `1rem`. Para obtener `rem` de acuerdo a px, basta con dividir los píxeles entre `16`: `-580px / 16 = 36.25rem`.

Comment: Otra cosa, deberías de poner un ejemplo **funcional** en donde se pueda reproducir el problema para poder ofrecer una solución. De lo contrario, es probable que no recibas suficiente ayuda.

Comment: @guzgarcia, me lo imaginaba es dificil una funcion simple que se adapte al zoom. aún es nueva todavía para que el futuro se arregle este punto. El rem lo estudiaré y probarla. Gracias de todas las maneras. Saludos.

Comment: Yo te recomiendo mucho usar un pre/post procesador para CSS. En lo personal te recomiendo [PostCSS](http://postcss.org/). Implementa el futuro estándar CSS4, como variables, funciones, etc. Además, tiene muchos plugins como normalize, cssnano, etc., uno de ellos, [pxtorem](https://github.com/cuth/postcss-pxtorem) te compila una hoja de estilos transformando los `px` a `rem`.